# Get wrong answer in bitwise and on unsigned int on c?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-and

I have two numbers, `2147483648` and `808529920` stored in `unsigned int` variables but, when I do their bitwise *and* in C, the answer is supposed to be 1, but I get 0.

808529920 in binary looks like:

```
110000001100010011000000000000
```

2147483648 in binary looks like:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
```

```
unsigned int a = 808529920;
unsigned int b = 2147483648;

unsigned int ret = a & b;
```

Comment: Don't just describe the code in words. Show the exact code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, show a small bit of complete code that anyone can copy exactly as shown to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `answer supposed to be 1` ... who says?

Comment: We have two even numbers here, their intersection (bitwise AND) is for sure even as well.

Comment: `110000001100010011000000000000` is only 30 bits. The full 32-bit integer is `00110000001100010011000000000000`

Comment: Thanks! I just use python format to see the binary type, so I didn't realize it only show me 30 bits.

Answer (score 3):

```
 808529920 == 0b00110000001100010011000000000000
2147483648 == 0b10000000000000000000000000000000
```

There are no bits in common, so you should get 0 not 1.

Comment: Thanks! When I format the int into binary type on python, I just see the first bit, but i didn't realize all there still have two zero bits before the format bit string.

Comment: @user9188191 `f'{yournumber:32b}'`